# C++ enum does not name a type

Tags: c++, enums

I'm working on a problem where part of the code looks like the one below:

```
class x
{
  type t;
public:
  enum type { A, B, C, D};
};
```

g++ says `type does not name a type`. I tried changing `type t` to `x::type t` or compiling with C++11 to no avail.

It's a simple problem so there's no linking, aka, I didn't include any header file.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: `type` needs to be declared before it is used.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. My memory is probably blanking out on this concept. But I remember when g++ compiles C++ code, it only starts to resolve the references within the class after the final ';'. For example, you can call a member function before defining it within a class without using forward declaration. Do I not understand it right?

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `type` before you create a variable of type `type`. If you move type 't' after the declaration of `type` in your code it will fix the error. Change this

```
class x
{
   type t;
public:
   enum type { A, B, C, D};
};
```

to this

```
class x
{
public:
    enum type { A, B, C, D};
private:
    type t;
};
```

and it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know `type` is an enum because it was used before it was declared.

Try this:

```
class x
{
public:
  enum type { A, B, C, D};
private:
  type t;
};
```